# How to "encode" this simple expression in template Haskell?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I have a call `myFun @m @d`. And now I want to code it for my template Haskell. I try

```hs
let myFunCall = AppTypeE (VarE $ mkName "myFun") (AppT (VarT $ mkName "m") (VarT $ mkName "d"))
```

But it's invalid because I get `myFun @(m d)`.

To be honest I have not idea even how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any other sort of function application in Haskell, it associates argument by argument. I.e. `myFun @m @d` is `(myFun @m) @d`. Each of the `@` is an `AppTypeE` of its own, i.e. you need

```
   AppTypeE (AppTypeE (VarE $ mkName "myFun") ...) ...
```